# Sub works from "Book1" but not from "PERSONAL.XLSB

Tags: vba, excel-2016

I use Excel 2016 and this Sub is copied from: [VBA to remove numbers from start of string/cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42716936/vba-to-remove-numbers-from-start-of-string-cell)

```
Sub RemoveNonDigits()
  Dim X As Long, Z As Long, LastRow As Long, CellVal As String
  Const StartRow As Long = 1
  Const DataColumn As String = "A"

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, DataColumn).End(xlUp).Row
  For X = StartRow To LastRow
    CellVal = Cells(X, DataColumn)
    While IsNumeric(Left(CellVal, 1))   ' Here
      CellVal = Mid(CellVal, 2)         ' all digits at the start
    Wend                                ' are removed
    Cells(X, DataColumn) = trim(CellVal)
  Next

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

When I copy this sub from your site and paste it into a new module, in a new workbook (Book1), it works fine.

When I copy the sub from Book1 and paste it into a new module in PERSONAL.XLSB, I get this error:

"Compile error:
Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment".

"Sub RemoveNonDigits()" is highlighted in yellow and "trim" is highlighted in blue.

Can anyone tell me why the Sub works from "Book1" but not from "PERSONAL.XLSB"?

Any help is much appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The code should work if it is run from PERSONAL.XSLB (I tested it and it worked for me. The problem is more likely to be that the sheet containing the data is not currently active.

Comment: Thanks @Jane That makes sense but how do I do that? I'm quite new to VBA. The workbook is copied all the time (new names) and the worksheet has a button linked to this sub.

Comment: Would you check if you have a custom function called `trim` in the other workbook?? Or is it a blank workbook? Try substituting your statement with `= VBA.Trim(CellVal)` to see.

Comment: Thanks @A.S.H No "trim" function. It worked with "= VBA.Trim(CellVal)"! This was just a part of my code to clean up data from internet. I had to do the same with some other statements too. Is it possible you can explain why this works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you had another function somewhere called `trim` which took other parameters, or may be a property or a variable in some other module, referenced library or add-in.

The call `VBA.Trim` solved your problem by *disambiguating* the function's name. By prefixing the function's name with `VBA.`, you tell the compiler *explicitly* that you want to invoke the function `Trim` that is built-in with VBA, not any other one.

Prefixing with `VBA.`  is not usually necessary, but sometimes it helps disambiguate name resolution.

Comment: Thanks a lot @A.S.H , I got it and everything is working fine now :)

Comment: @Soidog You're Welcome, glad to help.